# Looking for examples of costs for deploying web app to Azure vs 3rd party hosting

Tags: azure

Ok, I know there is a pricing calculator, and every app is different in terms of scale etc.  However, take your "typical" CRUD type app with a SQL database.
Assumptions:

- asp.net core web app with 5 screens
- 50 users
- 5GB database w/approx. 5 mil records total in all tables
- daily user transactions might update 5 MB of data
- daily upload of data approx. 10 MB

Other apps and databases will be added in time.  Nothing special

So I used the pricing calculator, maybe I dont know what Im doing, but Im looking at a montly cost between $1000-2000

Now, looking at a 3rd party web hosting ( I know apples/oranges) mostly costs are under $100/month.

What am I overlooking?

**[ update ]**
Screenshot of options used in pricing calculator

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show how you came up with that figure so we can see what assumptions you made -- can you break it down to individual items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database is your big differentiator here. You have selected a pretty expensive DB SKU, which gives you much more performance and availability than you would get with 3rd part provider. You are also getting a whole DB server which can host multiple DB's (under the same cost) rather than a single DB.

If you want to bring this down, look to use the  DTU based purchase model which is a lot cheaper. You can also look to reduce the amount of cores and service tier.